# Multiple Sites in IIS. HTTPS Conflict

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, server, hosting

I'm using a windows server with IIS v6.1 (but same on older versions)

I am hosting multiple websites on the same IP address and each website has a unique domain, which works fine... pretty standard.

I've recently set up 1 of those sites with a HTTPS / SSL certificate, which is working fine for that site.

However.. when I go to one of the other sites using httpS, it is now being bound to the site with SSL, which is causing incorrect google rankings and loads of other issues.

Other than getting a new IP address, which isn't possible in the current hosting situation..  does anyone know another way I can prevent this from happening?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can only do multiple domain same IP SSL if you change the port number with < IIS 8. I recently moved to IIS 10 and it works great. https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/ssl-host-headers-iis-8.htm

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/761089/iis-7-5-cant-configure-two-ssl-certificates-under-one-ip-adress

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to IIS 8.0 or above and use SNI (Server Name Indication) feature to hosts multiple SSL sites within the same IIS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability